# Rust FFI: function with multiple string pointers; first parameter has aggregated value from subsequent string pointers

Tags: rust, ffi

Below, I have simple function with two string pointers parameters.  First parameter is expression (i.e. value = "foo") and second parameter is json (i.e. value = {"foo":{"bar":{"baz":true}}}).  When I execute the test I get the following:

result:

```
expression foo{"foo":{"bar":{"baz":true}}}
json {"foo":{"bar":{"baz":true}}}
```

expected:

```
expression foo
json {"foo":{"bar":{"baz":true}}}
```

Function code

```
use std::ffi::{CStr, CString};
use std::os::raw::c_char;
use std::panic::catch_unwind;
use std::str;

#[no_mangle]

pub extern "C" fn execute(expression: *const c_char, json: *const c_char) {
    let result = catch_unwind(|| {
        let expression_cstr = unsafe {
            assert!(!expression.is_null());
            CStr::from_ptr(expression)
        };
        let json_cstr = unsafe {
            assert!(!json.is_null());
            CStr::from_ptr(json)
        };
        let expression_str =
            str::from_utf8(expression_cstr.to_bytes()).map(|e| println!("expression {}", e));
        let json_str = str::from_utf8(json_cstr.to_bytes()).map(|j| println!("json {}", j));
    });
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use std::os::raw::c_char;

    #[test]
    fn it_works() {
        let expression = "foo".as_ptr() as *const c_char;
        super::execute(
            expression,
            "{\"foo\":{\"bar\":{\"baz\":true}}}".as_ptr() as *const c_char,
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `execute` function expects null-terminated C strings, however Rust strings don't use null-terminated representation, so `"foo".as_ptr() as *const c_char` doesn't give you a valid C string (and you typically get extra data when you try to treat it as one, although it's technically undefined behavior).

The proper way is to convert to `CString` before calling your function, to make sure that your inputs have the correct reprensentation:

```rust
#[test]
pub fn it_works() {
    let expression = CString::new("foo").unwrap();
    let json = CString::new("{\"foo\":{\"bar\":{\"baz\":true}}}").unwrap();

    super::execute(
        expression.as_ptr(),
        json.as_ptr(),
    );
}
```

Comment: Another option is to include the null-terminator yourself: `"foo\0"`